# No emails sent automatically when someone joins a group

Tags: civimail, profile

The documentation says:

> After people subscribe to mailing list groups—via the subscribe link
>   or a profile—CiviCRM will automatically send them an email asking them
>   to confirm their subscription. Until they click the confirmation link
>   in the email, their contact information will appear in CiviCRM with
>   their group subscription set to Pending. When they confirm, CiviCRM
>   will automatically change their group subscription status to Added and
>   they will be sent a welcome message. (Note: When users subscribe to
>   multiple groups at once, a confirmation email is sent for each group
>   separately.)

I cannot get this to work. Civimail works fine. Send mail to individuals or to a list that resulted from a search works fine.

People join a group through a profile. The advanced settings in the profile has the group name ("Volunteers") and a return ddress but **no emails are sent**.

I have checked to see if there is a scheduled job that handles this but could not find one that seemed relevant.

Comment: I've also tried adding a groups field to the profile but that had no effect.

Comment: Is it working via the Subscribe page but not via Profile - or neither. Also i thought there was a setting where you could disable confirmation. Can't spot it in the UI - might be in civicrm.settings.php but not about to go digging to check

Comment: I wan unable to find a setting to disable confirmations in civicrm.settings.php and if there is one in the UI somewhere, I was unable to find that too. When I go to www.letsbanfracking.org/civicrm/mailing/subscribe, I get a 404 error, even when logged in as a super-user.

Comment: The link to the subscribe page is http://letsbanfracking.org/civ/mail-list-subscribe. Not as documented. We are receiving notifications when using that link but not with using the profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your settings in **Administer > CiviMail > CiviMail Component Settings**:

[image: CiviMail Settings]

Comment: heh - great - don't recall when the option was added so double opt-in for the profile was separate but seems to be the answer Dennis needs.

Comment: No problem at all!